# Allow moderators to show removed posts in the reputation tab of other users profiles

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, moderators

Currently, if a user looks at the reputation tab on their profile, they have a checkbox at the bottom allowing them to show the reputation changes from removed posts:

[image: "show removed posts" on own profile's reputation tab]

Moderators should have this ability as well, but we currently can't see that, we see what everyone else sees:

[image: lack of "show removed posts" on other user's profile reputation tab]

It would help in situations like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127976/i-lost-about-110-rep-last-night-whered-it-go) where we're trying to discern how a user has unexpectedly lost reputation (if not for any other reason, to rule out that it wasn't self-deleted posts that were the case).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is incorrect, moderators see a view that *includes* removed content, you just don't have a checkbox to *disable* it.  We figured you guys were all grown up and could handle seeing deleted content without freaking out so...

*Note:* moderators still cannot see a downvotes that a user casts, that's still a "your own profile" only thing.

Comment: @casperOne - honestly we have a ton of preferences already, we didn't want to add one *just for moderator views of other user's profiles* here, it's overkill and you guys can handle seeing deleted content without freaking out.

Comment: @casperOne - that's not a valid argument this...that user didn't have a removed item for 110, you would have no additional information that you have now (since you'd **already** see it, were it there).

Comment: @casperOne - You completely misread what I was saying.  I was saying mods **wouldn't** freak out (as most users would seeing a high negative number).  Please read up, we have reasons for the behavior mechanics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion

Comment: I think he wants something like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127064/view-site-with-a-specific-reputation-value-lower-than-your-own-of-course-or-as

Comment: @Manishearth No, that's separate.

Comment: @Manishearth - I don't think we'll be doing that, that's a ***HUGE*** feature request without a corresponding payoff.  We allow this for developers only, and even then it only works in a dev environment, it's dangerous enough to be `if #DEBUG`.

Comment: @NickCraver: You misunderstand me--I was referring to the intention of the post (which is the same as the linked one). He wants a way to see this portion of the site as consistently as the other users. Currently, it seems that mods can't tell if a post is deleted in the rep view (afaik), so they won't realise what's wrong and have to dig  extra. I know that allowing Sudos would be a disaster if not done properly.

Comment: @Manishearth I don't want to see it consistently as another user, initially, I was wondering why we didn't have the option, but Nick points out (correctly) that they've built it in, so we *always* see it.  That's good, and answers the question.  My initial comment to this post was about consistency.

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].