# Moderators see a different reputation result than regular users

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, moderator-abilities

Related: **[Moderators should have the check-box to show/hide removed posts on user reputation pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242533/moderators-should-have-the-check-box-to-show-hide-removed-posts-on-user-reputati)** (Follow-on)

We have a user [(Hi Janos)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos?tab=reputation&sort=time) who deleted an answer yesterday. They also managed to cap their reputation as well. When regular users inspect the profile of that user they see:

***NOTE THE 260 AT THE TOP***

[image: Regular View]

The user himself sees the exact same thing.

As a moderator, I see ***NOTE THE 142 AT THE TOP***:

[image: Moderator view]

The user reports that their text-based /reputation page shows 260 for yesterday.

Where's the bug? I presume the moderator page is incorrectly calculating the day's rep. I have confirmed that other mods on the site also see 142 as the rep.

Note that the user-graphs are also affected by this:

[image][image]

Comment: The user should see the `removed` entry in their rep history *as well*. Unless they have that checkbox turned off..

Comment: @MartijnPieters But how much did the user gain yesterday? That should show the same for everyone, should it not?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: they gained 260 from votes, etc. but the reputation gained before from that post is no longer there from the moment it is deleted, so they also lost 118 points (as if they had never earned it).

Comment: That's not true, though @MartijnPieters - their /reputation text-page shows 260 for the day, and they had numerous 'no-score' upvotes after the deletion too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Should the total for the day show +260 or +118 ? +260 seems more reasonable to me.

Comment: @rolfl: that's because the deletion entry is only informative. The actual effect of the deletion is to nullify the original votes. The deletion does not affect the reputation cap for that day, because none of the reputation now gone was earned that day.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: you have the choice; hide `removed` entries by toggling the checkbox.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a bug. You are seeing `removed` entries, which are entries in the log to inform you that a post was removed and what the net effect is of the removal. The total at the top reflects the daily reputation change *including* that net effect.

The user sees the exact same thing *depending on a checkbox*. There is a little checkbox at the bottom of the reputation page that says *show removed posts*.

If it is off, the user sees what other users see, +260 (provided they didn't downvote any answers). If it is on, they see what moderators see, the `removed` line, and their reputation change reflects the deletion. The UI will show them they gained +142 for the day.

Remember that deletion of a post results in nullification of the original votes that gave the reputation. It is as if the original votes were never cast; any effect on the reputation cap on previous days of those votes is also re-calculated. The `removed` entry in yesterday's reputation log is only there as an informative entry to let you know at what time the deletion took effect, and what the net reputation result was.

Comment: Does the deletion affect the reputation cap for the day when the deleted reputation was actually earned?

Comment: Moderators doesn't have that checkbox though, which (to me) is more about what this question is about - the moderator aspect of things.

Comment: @janos: yes. The votes are no longer there, so any votes that were pushing you over the cap on days in the past will now no longer do so. *Other* votes that were capped may now take their place, of course.

Comment: What do you mean, "moderators doesn't have that checkbox" @simon? They *should* - I do, and I don't recall doing anything special there. Tell 'em to scroll all the way down...

Comment: @Shog9 - I have it on my own page, but not on any other user's page. Regardless, I would expect the daily rep total to be accurate.

Comment: @rolfl it *is* accurate. The votes are correctly capped; the deleted votes were not cast on the day the post was deleted, so why should they lower the cap? The user still have their 20+ upvotes that day, regardless of the delete.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - which vote count is accurate? 142 or 260? And, the daily total should reflect the daily total, whichever one that is. ***One*** of them has to be wrong.

Comment: @rolfl '260' is not a vote count. It is a reputation delta. That day the reputation changed by 142 points through various events. One of those events was the deletion of a post, which triggered the nullification of votes cast earlier in the users timeline.

Comment: @Shog9 - [moderators have no checkbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127989/241497)

Comment: MartijnPieters - no, that day, reputation changed by 260, not 142, and moderators see the wrong value. It's a bug, despite @shog saying it's a bug-by-design.

Comment: @rolfl if the checkbox is disabled all voting for that deleted post is removed from the user reputation history too; earlier +10 votes for that post will be no longer be listed. With the checkbox on those votes become visible again *and* you see the moment in time those votes for the deleted post effectively became null and void.

Comment: Well, we clearly disagree, and since I have no way of seeing a person's reputation for the day, it's a problem.

Comment: @rolfl you can't have it both ways; the now-nullified votes visible in the user history and the deletion not having an impact. Then the books don't balance. This way the daily reputation changes add up properly to the current total reputation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/789/discussion-between-rolfl-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: 260 is accurate, @rolfl - that's what was earned for the day. If you check the box, then a different set of rules are in play, and 142 becomes accurate. If you don't see the box, report a bug.

Comment: @Shog9 - I HAVE NO BOX TO CHECK ... ;-)

Comment: @rolfl in other words: this is part and parcel of proper reputation accounting. The `/reputation` view shows rep deltas with the deleted post removed, the user reputation tab shows it with the deleted post votes in place as well as the deletion. That way you as a moderator at least have an accurate historical record as to what happened with voting as regards to the post.

Comment: @Shog9 the real issue here then is that rofl wants that checkbox so as to see what the user sees when *they* have that checkbox disabled. And that makes this a dupe of [casperOne's feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127983).

Comment: @Shog9 and I can kinda sorta see the point of that, whereas Nick clearly *doesn't*.

Comment: Related: [Moderators should have the check-box to show/hide removed posts on user reputation pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242533/moderators-should-have-the-check-box-to-show-hide-removed-posts-on-user-reputati)