# Moderators should have the check-box to show/hide removed posts on user reputation pages

Tags: bug, reputation, moderator-abilities

> 260 is accurate, @rolfl - that's what was earned for the day. If you check the box, then a different set of rules are in play, and 142 becomes accurate. If you don't see the box, report a bug.  –  [Shog9♦ 27 mins ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242530/moderators-see-a-different-reputation-result-than-regular-users/242531?noredirect=1#comment792863_242531)

*I don't see the box, here's the bug report... ;-)*

Moderators occasionally need to be able to see users reputation pages in the same way they other users do. Unfortunately, as a result of this [feature implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127989/241497) the ability for moderators to change between viewing pages with and without removed posts does not exist (by design).

As Nick Craver says:

> This is incorrect, moderators see a view that includes removed
>   content, you just don't have a checkbox to disable it. We figured you
>   guys were all grown up and could handle seeing deleted content without
>   freaking out so...

I agree that moderators should be seeing deleted content, but, moderators also need to be able to see things without the deleted content too.

Removing this ability is a bug, as Shog9 says... ;)

The result is that it leads to confusion between moderators and users when their perspective on reputation is different.

Related: [Moderators see a different reputation result than regular users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242530/moderators-see-a-different-reputation-result-than-regular-users)