# "See page as it would appear at given reputation" moderator feature

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Normally, moderators are shown some things by default that even a high-reputation user does not see by default. This is useful in many situations, but can sometimes cause uncertainty about what the page will look like to a regular user.

I would like to see a feature that allows a diamond moderator only to **enter any desired reputation level, and the page is re-rendered** (possibly locally) to display as it would display to a regular user on the site with the given reputation.

This would seem to nicely complement the possibility of opening a private browser window and navigating to the page to see how it would appear to a user that is not logged in to the site. Since it would be for diamond moderators only, it also would not expose any information that is not already available to the user who uses said feature.

Comment: I think this is a valuable request, and as it so closely relates to some further suggestions in the potential duplicate mentioned by @random, I'm going to go there to express my feelings.  Thanks for bringing it up!